# What is the best way to use stylesheets with webpack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am using nodejs + webpack. What is the best way to use stylesheet with webpack?
I don't want to link the css file directly in my index.html even though it works.

Comment: By importing it? Why not in the HTML file?

Comment: Is it a good practice if I link it in html @AndrewLi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a great relevant [guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-css/#using-css-loader) to using css with webpack from our new docs page. I believe using css-loader (with style-loader), should answer this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [html webpack plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin)

This plugin will generate `index.html` and adds all required scripts and stylesheets generated by webpack.

Hope this helps!